# Data Driven Framework Limitation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, excel

I am currently using a data driven framework for my automation testings with Excel.

When I have more than 255 characters, in my Excel cell my tests fail.

Are there any other alternatives with Excel or Selenium that I can use when there are more than 255 characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Standard CSV shouldn't have such a limitation. Database, XML, JSON, plain text or hardcoded. The possibilities are limitless.